# How do I use certificate based authentication with SOAP?

Tags: web-services, curl, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get the wsdl from a soap ws but I'm getting a:

> ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

error, when I tried to access https://dummyurl.com:8446/data.php?wsdl from my browser.

I've been given 3 files: ca.crt, pablo.crt and pablo.key but I don't know how to use these files in order to authenticate with this service.

I've also tried to use curl to get the wsdl (without any luck)

> curl -k https://dummyurl.com:8446/data.php?wsdl -v -key=pablo.key -cacert=ca.crt -cert=pablo.crt

So my question is, how can I use this certificates and key in order to authenticate and and get the wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

You might find documentation useful
   https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html